# How to update the /etc/profile within the sudo bash without rebooting or logging out

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, debian, environment-variables

Currently right now I am creating a script that updates the path and environment variable of the profile within my raspberry-pi

I have created a script within the `/etc/profile.d/sdk.sh` to create a environment variable. Now it does not updates within my `env`, How can I add/update my environment variable without rebooting or logging-out of the system.

My script:

```
SDK_SH_FILE="/etc/profile.d/sdk.sh"
EXPORT_SDK_HOME="export SDK_HOME=/edit/"
echo -e "$EXPORT_SDK_HOME" > "$SDK_SH_FILE"
```

It is run using: `cat my-script | sudo bash`

Currently it is not updating my env unless I logout or reboot the system.

Answer (score 3):

After editing `sdk.sh`, you need to load it in the current shell with:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sdk.sh
```

Comment: Is there a way to load it within the script file?

Comment: No, you can't modify the current shell's environment in a child process.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices for this job:

```
source /etc/profile.d/sdk.sh
```

OR

```
. /etc/profile.d/sdk.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried out [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s suggestion. It works to update the current bash session. If you close the terminal window and open a new one, you need to run `source` again.

Also, the new values are only concatenated to the environment variable rather than replacing the old values. So, it is still better to log out and log in again.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the current shell environment by **sourcing** a script, because that way it runs in the same shell instance, but you need to acquire privileges to update `sdk.sh` (so shell redirections won't work), right?

The solution is to separate the write operation that requires privileges (calling only that via `sudo`).

Here the UNIX toolbox comes to the rescue with `tee`, a program that takes files as parameters, reads from it's standard input, and copies to it's standard output and to the files specified as parameters; this being a separate program, and opening it's parameters on it's own, can be called with `sudo` just fine.

### Solution

```bash
export SDK_HOME=/edit/
typeset -p SDK_HOME | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/sdk.sh >/dev/null
```

Now, you need to **source** this file, instead of calling it, like so:
`. ./my-script`.

Here I used `typeset -p` to avoid repeating myself, it reproduces the declarations of the specified variables.

### Variables and startup files

Variables are handed down from process to process in the **environment**, which is a portion of memory every process gets from it's parent process.

Shells behave differently depending on how they're called; a **login shell** will load a user/system profile file, i.e. `/etc/profile` (or a similar file at the home directory), and the rest of the session will get variables from it through the environment (thus updates to the file don't matter); normally all other interactive instances of the shell load a secondary file, in the case of BASH it's `$HOME/.bashrc` or `/etc/bashrc` (which login shells don't load).